# Retrieve URL of shared object after Like or Share event

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, xfbml

I've got a Like button (using XFBML, but can also use HTML5 version if necessary) on key static pages on my site. I can tell when someone clicked the Like button and record that event, but I'm wondering if there's a way to see the actual Like post including any comment that the person added. I know each object should have its own URL, but is it possible to capture this? The idea would be to have the permalink of the Like and comment recorded in our database.

Been through the developer docs and can't seem to find something that does this, but I'm pretty sure I've seen it done. Thanks.